# Wiki on a Stick - can it work on Chrome?

Tags: java, jar, wiki

I've been using "Wiki on a Stick" for several years and have a few wikis that are full of info (and would be a pain to try to move onto something else). A year or two ago the editing features stopped working on all browsers aside from IE, apparently due to how those browsers handle Java or something.

However, I really hate using IE, so I was trying again to see if I could get it to work on Chrome. When I try it on Chrome, the error message reads: "The TiddlySaver Java applet was not available. Please check that the TiddlySaver.jar is in the same directory as this WoaS and that you have enabled Java permissions for it."

It IS in the same directory, so it sounds like all I need to do is "enable Java permissions for it"... but HOW do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Java applets are dead. And chrome does not support them anymore.

Comment: First of all, this technically is offtopic for this site. Second, it looks like you're out of luck on that one: [Chrome officially discontinued support for Java applets of any kind](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml). You will need to contact original developer, or reverse engineer some things to fashion a Javascipt-app of a kind from this applet.

Comment: You can also try and see if another browser works. Like [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Problems-with-add-ons-plugins-or/How-to-allow-Java-on-trusted-sites/ta-p/6206), for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I have some bad news for you. Chrome (and practically all other non-legacy browsers) do no longer support the NPAPI, [the technology behind Java "applets".](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) So the applet will never run again. *Especially* not in Chrome.

The [most recent activity in WoaS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stickwiki/) was more than five years ago, the board and mailing list died, so I doubt there will be an updated version anytime soon.

But I have learnt from the documentation, that the wiki's content is stored in a well-formated XHTML-File; so the parsing/extraction of your content shouldn't be that hard. But this is just from an outside perspective, I did not look into the product any further.

My advice would be to migrate you data as fast as possible, java applet technologie is a dead end.